# Is there a shortcut to jump to the right-most cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I am looking for the Excel shortcut that allows you to jump to the right-most cell on the same row in a formatted table.

I would have expected this shortcut to be the <kbd>End</kbd> button, as the behaviour I want seems to be the opposite of pressing the <kbd>Home</kbd> button. Unfortunately this only turns on `end mode` and does not jump to the right-most cell.

The closest shortcut I have found to the behaviour I want is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> as this jumps to the next screen on the right.

Things that don't work:

- <kbd>End</kbd> - this just enabled `End Mode`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> - this achieves the column change I want but also changes the row.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow Key</kbd> - This jumps until a cell changes state (blank to filled or vice versa)

Keen to avoid anything that uses macros/VBA.

Comment: From what I can see, a third party tool or a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>.

<kbd>Home</kbd> to go to the beginning of the row, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go to the last column on the row above, then <kbd>↓</kbd> to go back down to the original row.

If your original row is the first row, the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> part will take you to the last column in the current row and you can skip the <kbd>↓</kbd> step at the end.

[image]

Comment: `Shift` + `Tab` only seems to move one column to the left. If it is in the first column it does nothing.

Comment: I added a gif to show that it works (for me at least)

Comment: Tested again works with a table as per the original question. When I first commented I wasn't using a table. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`FlexYourData`'s way works in a formal Table, as you ask for. It does not work if not in a formal Table.

I believe that is because a Table is handled by Excel in many ways the way a highlighted range would be handled. And to note:  if you select the cells in the row and the one above it in a highlighted range, his method works there too.

It fits your request and is very simple to use.

I could not find or learn of a direct shortcut which would be about the only way to better it.

As for an alternative, not as good, but might fit some other need someday, and works whether in a formal Table or just a plain old range, would be to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to select the whole row (in a Table, it will limit itself to selecting only the Table's cells in that row, but that suits the result perfectly so...). Then the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to the next cell "left" which, since it "wraps around" is the XFD column cell, then <kbd>End</kbd>-<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> works too) to move left to the last used cell in the row, which is the desired cell.

So, not as elegant by a decent distance, but perhaps more useful in non-Table situations. And can also be used up or down which the other one cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you just hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>, or tap right a few times while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> will get you to column XFD in less than a second. Then just tap left arrow once to get to the last used cell. Bit of a pain, but only if you have lots of blanks interspersed between your data which isn't usually the case.

Answer (score 0):

Select first cell of the row. Shift+Space, then Shift+Enter, then Ctrl+Left Arrow. Alt+Page Down is also helpful for this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).